# Считывание данных из файла через перегрузку оператора С++

Tags: c++, классы, c++11, перегрузка-операторов, ввод

Сама задача такова. Виртуальную функцию ввода данных из файла 
Подскажите как заставить программу считывать с каждой строчки новые данные. То есть в файле `vhod.txt` есть значения

```
1.29  8 1e-3 1.73e-5
1.29 10 1e-3 1.73e-5
1.29 12 1e-3 1.73e-5
1.29 14 1e-3 1.73e-5
```

Как сделать так, что бы при каждом след обращении к функции `void input()` она считывала на строчку ниже? То есть сначала данные 1, потом 2 и т.д.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
class abstact
{
  protected:
    double f;
  public:
    virtual void input() = 0;
    virtual void output() = 0;
    virtual void rachet() = 0;
};

class racheti: public abstact
{
  private:
    double ksi;
    double speed;
    double alfa;
    double ro;
    double Relson;
    double nu;
    double S;
  public:
    racheti()
    {
        S = 1;
    }
    racheti(double s, double Ro, double Speed, double Alfa, double Nu)
    {
        S = s;
        ro = Ro;
        speed = Speed;
        alfa = Alfa;
        nu = Nu;
    }
    racheti(const racheti& src)
    {
        S = src.S;
        ro = src.ro;
        speed = src.speed;
        alfa = src.alfa;
        nu = src.nu;
    }
    void input()
    {
        ifstream fvh("vhod.txt");
        fvh >> ro;
        fvh >> speed;
        fvh >> alfa;
        fvh >> nu;
    }
    void output()
    {
        cout << "Paramiters : "  << endl << " S     = " << S << endl <<
             " Ro    = " << ro << endl << " Speed = " << speed << endl <<
             " Alfa  = " << alfa << endl << " Nu    = " << nu << endl;
        cout << endl << "F = " << f << " Relson = " << Relson << " KSI = " <<
             ksi << endl << endl;
    }
    void rachet()
    {
        Relson = (speed * alfa * ro) / nu;

        if (Relson <= 2)
        {
            ksi = 24 / Relson;
        }
        else if (Relson > 2 && Relson <= 500)
        {
            ksi = 18.5 / (pow(Relson, 0.6));
        }
        else if (Relson > 500)
        {
            ksi = 0.44;
        }

        f = ksi * S * ((ro * pow(speed, 2)) / 2);
    }
    friend ifstream& operator >> (ifstream& ifs, racheti& x);
    friend ofstream& operator << (ofstream& ofs, racheti& c);
};
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "Russian");
    int i, n = 7;
    racheti* g;
    g = new racheti[n];
    cout << "Массив элементов ";
    cout << "Введите N (Максимум елементов = 7) = ";
    cin  >> n;
    ifstream fvh("vhod.txt");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        g[i].input();
        g[i].rachet();
        g[i].output();
    }

    ofstream viv("vivod.txt");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        viv << g[i] << endl;
    }

    racheti r(1.0, 1.29, 10.0, 1e-3, 1.73e-5), r1;
    cout << "Конструктор инициализации" << endl;
    r1 = r;
    r.rachet();
    r.output();
    cout << "Конструктор копирования" << endl;
    r1.rachet();
    r1.output();
    cout << "R1 == R :" << (r1 == r);
    return 0;
}

ifstream& operator >> (ifstream& ifs, racheti& x)
{
    ifs >> x.ro;
    ifs >> x.speed;
    ifs >> x.alfa;
    ifs >> x.nu;
    return ifs;
}
ofstream& operator << (ofstream& ofs, racheti& c)
{
    ofs << "Paramiters : " << endl << " Ro    = " << c.ro << endl <<
        " Speed = " << c.speed << endl << " Alfa  = " << c.alfa << endl <<
        " Nu    = " << c.nu << endl;
    ofs << " Relson = " << c.Relson << " KSI = " << c.ksi << endl;
    ofs << " S = "  << c.S;
    ofs << endl;
    ofs << "Result : " << " F =  " << c.f;
    ofs << endl;
    return ofs;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно **НЕ** делать в одной функции двух вещей - открытия файла и чтения. Вот такой код

```
void input(ifstream& fvh)
{
    fvh >> ro;
    fvh >> speed;
    fvh >> alfa;
    fvh >> nu;
}
```

вас спасет. Открывайте файл в другом месте, и чтение будет последовательным.

Но я бы рекомендовал даже выполнять чтение **не** в члены класса, а во временные переменные, и проверять, все ли считано нормально. И только считав всё и убедившись, что все в порядке - присваивал бы значения реальным членам класса.

А функцию заставил бы возвращать ссылку на поток - чтоб можно было убедиться в корректности ее работы.

Тем более что файл вы лишний раз все равно открываете:

```
ifstream fvh("vhod.txt");

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    g[i].input();
    g[i].rachet();
    g[i].output();
}
```

Так что ваш код просто превратится в

```
ifstream fvh("vhod.txt");

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    g[i].input(fvh);
    g[i].rachet();
    g[i].output();
}
```

Comment: А как же тогда виртуальная функция?Она начитает тыкать на главный класс `class abstact`

Comment: Добавил скриншот

Comment: Исправил, спасибо!